# Implement Search field in ManytoManyField(Django Admin) models.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I currently have a ManytoManyField in Django where I can Select multiple Users with strg and mouseclick.
With much more Users it gets heavily complicated to search the User I want to select.
Is there a possibility to have a ManytoManyField, but also have a search_field for Users, so I can search and pick.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. What I was searching for was `filter_horizontal = '# put ManytoManyField reference name here'`